# Russian Search Poisoning? Which HTTP header to return?

Tags: apache, seo, http-headers

On two sites I manage one of our security routines has been detecting some problematic query strings mostly coming from the Russian Federation if the IPs aren't spoofed.

Eg `/member.php?data=phentermine-prices'"`  or `/member.php?data=get-online-viagra'"`

Our practice with SQL Injection flagged URIs (in this case the quotes) has been to use PHP `header("Location:")` and direct them elsewhere.

My question is whether this is sufficient or the best practice.  I know the site has not been compromised as I have cron jobs that alert me to any modified or new files within minutes but I am still concerned about back-link poisoning from aggregation sites. Should I send a 403 or 404 or 301 http header instead?

Bear in mind that the intended recipients of the rejection or redirection are legitimate spiders from Google et all following these spurious backlinks hosted on SEO bad guy sites. We want to let Google know these are spurious by our handling of the incoming request.

Comment: You'd be better off asking this question over on Server Fault - that's where all the 'cool' kids hang out

Comment: Maybe but I have a bounty on it here... :(

Comment: I tried to initiate close and move for you - but the bounty is a lock-out - I'll see if I can dig out some notes on best practices for you - but it's worth bearing in mind that bad people don't tend to play by the rules... so it might be worth employing a few tricks of your own :p

Answer (score 1):

There is no universal scenario for everyone. If issue detection from within PHP works for you - just use it. It is easier and more flexible. If you find an url that you deem invalid/illegal use standard HTTP responses:

```
header( 'HTTP/1.1 403' );
```

but this may suggest that sth is there and forbidden so may not prevent attacks - in this case use:

```
header( 'HTTP/1.1 404' );
```

If I were you I would not redirect. When redirecting - you must redirect somewhere. Where and what will this page contain? The less info you provide to anyone attacking your site - the better.

Answer (score 1):

If I detect an attacker in a PHP script, I also add `sleep(2)` to the file, so the hacker gets throttled. I had some nice guys trying to hack Joomla and this was the only ways to stop them. Simple HTTP headers (404, 403, 500...) didn't stop them from ddos'ing my server. They used a lot of different IP addresses from all over the world (probably a bot net) so I couldn't block the by IPs.

I think they don't care about HTTP headers if they know they have the correct URI. But if their script has to wait two seconds before getting a response, it gets too expensive for them to hack me.

Comment: I think your server gets throttled more than the hacker.

Comment: But it worked very good to get rid of the hacker. Better than different HTTP headers.

Comment: That's true (the hacker in particular probably did not even implement processing returned HTTP headers in the first place).

Answer (score 0):

It is neither sufficent nor is it the best practice.

I don't know what is your server setup, but as far as PHP goes, you could write a small php handler that detects those query strings and then write a deny rule in htacces based on the IP that requested URI.

If you could provide me with more details about your server setup, I'll gladly expand on the response.

Comment: Bear in mind that the intended recipients of the rejection or redirection are legitimate spiders from Google et all following these spurious backlinks hosted on SEO bad guy sites. We want to let Google know these are spurious by our handling of the incoming request. So I don't wish to blacklist the incoming traffic but copmmunicate that it is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

You're using PHP, so I guess you're on an Apache server? - if so then you can use **mod_rewrite** to stop the requests before they even reach your application.

There are a few techniques you could consider:

1. filtering from an IP address range:

   **RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^118\.87\.**
2. filter out suspicious query expressions:

   **RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^.*(viagra|phentermine|pharma|meds).***

Plenty more in [this tutorial](http://perishablepress.com/eight-ways-to-blacklist-with-apaches-mod_rewrite/)

Google has a tool for disavowing 'unnatural links' there is a [tutorial here](http://dbpmarketing.com/google-disavow-link-tool-guide/) - Google also have a [user guide](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/2648487?hl=en)

You could direct spurious requests to a script that logged the referrer URL - it would help with your blacklist file.